# New to extending Django user profiles, Need help creating a contacts/phone numbers list for each user in the database

Tags: django, model

I'm a bit new to Django and so far just been working with simple database/model configurations. But I'm beginning to run up against some limitations. I need to add a list of contacts for individual users that simply stores a collection of names and phone numbers.
But I see no way of doing that with the UserProfile model I have already created other than storing the whole list as a string or deserialized JSON in a single char or text field (yuck).

For example say i have to model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    #Persional Informaiton
    height                  = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=False,null=True)
    weight                  = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=False,null=True)
    birthday                = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=False,null=True)

    ###THIS IS THE FIELD I NEED TO ADD!!  
    #Contacts  
    contact_list            = models.SomeKindOfField() #could contain either an array or JSON??   

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'user_profiles'        

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

Are there other ways of doing this? I have also thought of creating a table for each user with "name" and "phone" columns but started to wonder if that would be a nightmare to manage.

I was doing a little research about using models.ForeignKey(User) but never quite grasped the implementation of it.

Any pointers here would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to do this in a standard relational DB way, there are a few options.

1. Add a `Contact` model with name and phone number as attributes and a ForeignKey to `UserProfile`. This would allow you to do `user_profile.contact_set.all()`. Or instead of a FK you could use a ManyToMany if you want multiple users to be able to share certain contacts.
2. If you actually want the phone numbers to be associated with user or user profile records, so that a user's contact list is other users instead of just assorted phone numbers and names, you could add the `phone_number` attribute to your UserProfile model. Then `contact_list = models.ManyToManyField('self')`. See docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical

Alternatively, if you don't want to worry about more model relationships and you're using postgres, you can use `hstore`, which allows you to store dictionary fields. See https://github.com/djangonauts/django-hstore for actual documentation on how this works.

Comment: @Gman-O, I don't have the rep to comment on your answer, womp. But glad you got it working! Re: best practice / my opinion, the `managed` and `db_table` properties are generally left to default. With Django 1.5+ you no longer need a UserProfile model and you can [create a custom `User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) instead. But hey, if it's all working...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks very much to baylee for that great explanation. I was able to get something up and running. I'm not completely sure if this would be considered best practice? And I'm also not certain if there are any security vulnerabilities or bottlenecks in this scheme but it seemed to work decently well in my applications.

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    height                  = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=False,null=True)
    weight                  = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=False,null=True)
    birthday                = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=False,null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'user_profiles'        
User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])

class UserContacts(models.Model):
    user                    = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name                    = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=False,null=True)
    phone                   = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=False,null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'user_contacts'
```

*views.py*

```
def add_contact(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        update_success = False
        form = addContact(request.POST or None)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                data = form.cleaned_data
                contact = form.save(commit=False)
                contact.user = request.user
                contact.save()
                form = addContact() #return blank form so user can continue adding to db
                update_success = True

        return render_to_response('contact_form.html',
                                  {'update_success':update_success,
                                   'form':form,
                                   },
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request),
                                  )
    else:
        return redirect('/accounts/login/')
```

*forms.py*

```
from django import forms
#Using Crispy forms helper object and bootstrap styling
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit, Layout, ButtonHolder
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import TabHolder, Tab
#Using Models from "project.account" app
from accounts.models import UserContacts

class addContact(forms.ModelForm):    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(addContact, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)    
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            TabHolder(
                Tab(
                    'Basic Information',
                        'name',   
                        'phone',   
                    ),
            ),
            ButtonHolder(
                        Submit('Save', 'Proceed', css_class='btn btn-lg btn-default')
                        ),
        )
    class Meta:
        model = UserContacts
        fields = (  
                  'name',   
                  'phone',   
                 )
```

Thanks Everyone!